# Understanding metafunction to find type in a pack of type

Tags: c++, templates

Need help to understand the code.

I am trying to understand this code which is used to find whether the type that we have passed is present in the remaining arguments.
Eg in the below code, I am trying to find whether `char` is present in remaining types that I have passed.
Now I am unable to understand how this code is returning the index of the type that I have passed along with other types.

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

namespace id_by_type_detail {

template <std::size_t I, typename... Args>
struct id_by_type : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I> {};

template <std::size_t I, typename T, typename U, typename... Args>
struct id_by_type<I, T, U, Args...> : id_by_type<I + 1, T, Args...> {};

template <std::size_t I, typename T, typename... Args>
struct id_by_type<I, T, T, Args...> : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I> {};

} // namespace id_by_type_detail

template <typename T, typename... Args>
using typeid_v = id_by_type_detail::id_by_type<0, T, Args...>;

template <typename T, typename... Args>
struct contains_v : std::conditional<typeid_v<T, Args...>::value == sizeof...(Args), std::false_type, std::true_type>::type {};

int main () {
    std::size_t a = typeid_v<char, bool, char, int, float, double>::value;
    std::cout<<a<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The first argument is the type I need to search in the remaining types mentioned in the `typeid_v<>`. The output for this program will be 1 which is the index of `char`.

Its the way `id_by_type` is specialized what I am unable to understand.

Thanks

Comment: Is there a specific thing about the code you don't understand? Explaining every language feature used in this snippet would take too much time.

Comment: Did you hit a problem with this code you're trying to solve?

Comment: I am new to c++ template so if you can atleast help with some references or topics related to this code piece which can help me understand this. @HolyBlackCat

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot I was trying to write a code in template which can help me find whether a type is present or not. Although its working correctly, but not written by me and now I am trying to understand what and how exactly this piece of code is doing this.

Comment: @PiyushVijay is there a particular part that you need help to understand? Is it the `::value == sizeof...(Args)` or the way `id_by_type` is specialized? I'll try to clarified the question and reopen it.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot its the way `id_by_type` is specialized what I am unable to understand.

Answer (score 1):

I try to explain how

```
std::size_t a = typeid_v<char, bool, char, int, float, double>::value;
```

is compiled. General facts:

1. The solution uses recursion.
2. `namespace id_by_type_detail` provides three templates for this.
3. The compiler will always choose the best matching specialization of a template.

Concerning the last item, cppreference.com provides a page for [partial template specialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization). Specifically, the “best matching” is explained in [Partial ordering](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization#Partial_ordering).

The first template

```
template <std::size_t I, typename... Args>
struct id_by_type : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I> {};
```

is the most general. It will terminate the recursion if none of the types matches.
It defines a struct with one member `size_t value = I;`. ([std::integral_constant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integral_constant))

The second template (actually, the partial specialization of first)

```
template <std::size_t I, typename T, typename U, typename... Args>
struct id_by_type<I, T, U, Args...> : id_by_type<I + 1, T, Args...> {};
```

is for recursion. Where for non-meta programming, a function call would be used, this is in meta-programming a type definition. In this case, it's done by deriving left side from right side. Please note, that

- right side has `I + 1` (increment passed argument `I`)
- argument `U` is removed from right side.

The third template (actually, the partial specialization of first)

```
template <std::size_t I, typename T, typename... Args>
struct id_by_type<I, T, T, Args...> : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I> {};
```

is the most special. It will terminate the recursion if second template parameter and 
third template parameter will have same type. As well as the first template, it defines a struct with one member `size_t value = I;`.

The last missing piece is the

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
using typeid_v = id_by_type_detail::id_by_type<0, T, Args...>;
```

which starts the recursion with `I = 0`.

So, for

```
std::size_t a = typeid_v<char, bool, char, int, float, double>::value;
```

it is resolved with

```
typeid_v<char, bool, char, int, float, double>::value
```

↓

```
id_by_type_detail::typeid_v<0, char, bool, char, int, float, double>::value
```

↓ (applying 2nd template)

```
id_by_type_detail::typeid_v<1, char, char, int, float, double>::value
```

↓ (applying 3rd template)

```
std::integral_constant<size_t, 1>
```

↓

```
struct {
  size_t value = 1;
  /// and some extra stuff
};
```

resulting in

```
size_t a = 1;
```

---

Another example for a type which is not in list:

```
std::cout << typeid_v<short, bool, char, int>::value << '\n';
```

it is resolved with

```
typeid_v<short, bool, char, int>::value
```

↓

```
id_by_type_detail::typeid_v<0, short, bool, char, int>::value
```

↓ (applying 2nd template)

```
id_by_type_detail::typeid_v<1, short, char, int>::value
```

↓ (applying 2nd template)

```
id_by_type_detail::typeid_v<2, short, int>::value
```

↓ (applying 2nd template)

```
id_by_type_detail::typeid_v<3, short>::value
```

↓ (applying 1st template)

```
std::integral_constant<size_t, 3>
```

↓

```
struct {
  size_t value = 3;
  /// and some extra stuff
};
```

resulting in

```
std::cout << 3 << '\n';
```

As far as I understood, the out of range result denotes the type was not found in list. The last template (I did not yet mention)

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
struct contains_v : std::conditional<typeid_v<T, Args...>::value == sizeof...(Args), std::false_type, std::true_type>::type {};
```

proves me right.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look first at the default template:

```
template <std::size_t I, typename... Args>
struct id_by_type : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I> {};
```

This is the default fallback. If none of the specializations are fit, this one will take.

Ok, now the second:

```
template <std::size_t I, typename T, typename U, typename... Args>
struct id_by_type<I, T, U, Args...> : id_by_type<I + 1, T, Args...> {};
```

This is the iteration of the algorithm. `T` is the type we are searching for, and `U` is the first type of the pack. `Args` is the rest. Let's give them this name:

```
template <std::size_t I, typename Search, typename First, typename... Rest>
struct id_by_type<I, Search, First, Rest...> : id_by_type<I + 1, Search, Rest...> {};
```

So... How is this an iteration?

`id_by_type` is inheriting from itself, but it's not an infinite recursion. It's a finite one since we are inheriting the class with different parameter.

How different? The `First` parameter is not sent.

Then, for it's next instantiation, `First` is extracted from the first element of `Rest`, and we also increment the counter `I`.

So this particular instantiation is interiting like this:

```
//                 |---- First
//  Search ---v    v     v------- Rest...
id_by_type<1, int, char, float, int> : id_by_type<2, int, float, int>
```

The `char` type is not sent to the parent.

So this this recursion will go on until `Rest...` is empty, since `First` cannot be extracted for the specialization to be picked. The primary template will be picked, inheriting from `std::integral_constant`, giving access to `::value`, in which is will be equal to the size of `Args...` since we incremented it as we removed elements.

> But wait! There's another specialization available!

Ah yes, indeed.

That one look a lot like the iteration specialization (with the full names):

```
template <std::size_t I, typename Search, typename... Rest>
struct id_by_type<I, Search, Search, Rest...> : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I> {};
```

So, when is this specialization is picked? Well, only if we can match `Search` to the first two parameter.

```
//                 |---- Search again
//  Search ---v    v     v------- Rest...
id_by_type<I, int, int, char, float> : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I>
```

So, this specialization is picked when the `Search` is the same as the parameter that comes after, the one that is labeled as `First` in the other specialization.

**That's it!**

This is like a comparison between the types. If the first two parameters are equal, return `I`. If they are not equal, return `id_by_type` with the compared parameter removed.

A pseudocode if that algorithm would look like this:

```
auto id_by_type(std::size_t I, type Search, type First, type[] Rest) -> std::size_t {
    if (Search == First) {
        // found specialization, return I
        return I;
    } else if (!Rest.empty()) {
        // iteration specialization, increment and drop first
        return id_by_type(I + 1, Search, Rest.first(), Rest.drop_first());
    } else {
        // primary template, type not found
        return I + 1;
    }
}
```